# str_replace for multiple img classes

Tags: php

I am currently trying to use a `str_replace()` to replace multiple unique image classes on my site. How is this possible to do.

```
preg_match('/src=".+?(\.jpg)/', $image, $src); 

if ($src) {
    $classedImg = str_replace('<img', '<img class="plant-img" ', $image);
    $src = str_replace(array('src="', '//'), array('','/'), $src[0]);
```

this is how it is currently set up and functioning to replace the class for all images but how would I go about doing this for multiple images setting up unique classes assigned each image.

Thank you.

Comment: A simple `foreach` perhaps?

Comment: Is this for a static web page or are you dynamically pulling the images from a database or folder?

Answer (score 0):

If your solution doesn't require php:

**Javascript**

Note: you can modify the function and add arguments. I am not sure I understand the reason for why you want a unique class, but you can just increment some variable like below.

```
<script>
function replaceClass() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("targetClass");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.add('replaceWithClass'+i); // Added the "+ i" to make unique
  }
}
</script>
```